# How to make Navigation Bar and Tab bar always visible on every screen even after implementing PushView controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8

I have a iPhone app in which  need to add UISearchbar on navigation bar,  so that user can search from any where inside the app. When User Searches it displays search result in a Tableview controller and  User can select any row which pushes to other controller.

Below is the Structure which i have in StoryBoard

- Navigation Controller

  - Tab Bar Controller

    - View Controller1
    - View Controller2
    - View Controller3
    - View Controller4

[image: Attached Story Board Screenshot]

I can successfully add the UIsearchbar on Navigationbar in ViewController 1

```
 UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage      imageNamed:SEARCH]];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20);

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture =
[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                        action:@selector(searchTapped:)];
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

self.searchButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:imageView];
self.searchButton.style = UIBarButtonItemStylePlain;
 self.searchButton.target = self;
 [self.searchButton setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
self.tabBarController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.searchButton;
```

I can successfully implement the Search results as well in Tableview controller but when user select row it Pushes to different controller. Below is the code which implmenetd to push to different controller.

```
 UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"  bundle: nil];
    EntityViewController *entityController = [mainStoryboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:ENTITYIDENTIFIER];
    entityController.dataDic = result;
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:entityController  animated:YES];
```

**The problem here is when it pushes to different controller the TabBar is completely hidden and Navigation bar right button is completely Hidden.**

I tried to Unhide the tab bar and Navigation bar but no effect. I tried all possibilities but nothing worked.

Can some one please let me know what is right approach to solve this issue.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Chonch is right, this answer is what works, you have to change your set up

Comment: added my comment to Chonch answer.

Comment: Added my comments to your comment... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help. I resolved the issue by making Tab Bar controller as TOP View and Navigation controller for each view ( as per requirement. I made SearchController separately so that user can search from any where inside the app.

[image: Current Implementation]

I updated this as it can be help full for those who needs to implement similar kind of requirement.

If there is a better approach of implementation please do provide your comments.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried switching the order of the UINavigationController and the UITabController?

Right now, it seems like you have a UINavigationController with a UITabController "inside" it. So, when you push something else to the UINavigationController, the UITabController is being pushed aside, as it is no longer relevant.

If you were to have the UITabController on the top most level, with the UINavigationController at each of the tabs (or only on the relevant ones), when you'll push another view controller to that UINavigationController, it won't affect the tab bar, since it will still be on the top most level, completely unaffected by the push.

I hope this helps. Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried do that . I made UITabController as topmost and UINavigationController for each tab. The Tabbar always sticks on the top but the issue is the Searchbar & Search Controller which i need to add on UINavigation controller has to be added for each tab and it becomes duplicate if i do that and i am not sure going this apporach is right or not.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're current structure is or what it is that you're trying to achieve, but maybe you can have your search controller on the topmost level as well (instead of having to re-implement it on each of the navigation controllers). Would that work?

Comment: Also, if you do find yourself having to add it to each of the controllers, please make sure to implement all of the search related logic and UI in one place and just add it multiple times so that the implementation (and potential bugs that will need to be resolved) will all be in one place and implemented one time only.

Comment: Kishore, it's like this, set up your storyboard like so : navController => tabbarController = > mulitple TABS, in theses tabs, you set this up: tab1 = navController => viewController (or tableViewController), tab2 = navController => viewController (or tableViewController), tab3 = navController => viewController (or tableViewController), etc. etc.

Comment: Thanks Chonch. I am trying to Implement search so that user can search any where in the app. But when user searches and clicks on the results then i am pushing to different view controller  which is creating the issue for me   [self.navigationController pushViewController:entityController animated:YES];

Comment: Larcerax : Thanks for reply. I got this idea but i feel this approach is not the right one . Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: If you detach the search logic and UI from the navigation controller or simply have the search bar know which navigation controller is currently the relevant one, you should be able to push the results controller without it affecting your hierarchy or display. If it doesn't maybe you can share your updated code and we can try to help...

Comment: Thanks Chouch. I'll try as you suggested and share the code . Thanks Again

Comment: so, Kishore, I don't know of any app that doesn't use embedded naivgationControllers like this. In fact, in produciton apps, I sometimes have had over 40 navigationControllers to do masssively advanced layouts

Comment: Any app that has a tabbarcontroller with the ability to navigation a PUSH from the current page at the TAB has a UINavigationController embedded in the UITabBar, look at Facebook, twitter, Vine, everyone does this, its really the only way to fly

Comment: Thanks for the Update. I am trying to implement the same way as you guys suggested. Will let you know if i face any issues.